# Toggle Menu individual List from enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Practicing some Jquery I have a simple un-ordered list that I want to expand when I press enter. but only the the one I press enter on not all of them. Possibly setting it up wrong. At the moment its expanding both items.

```
<nav>
<ul>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li>
        <a href="">Sub Menu 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li>
        <a href="">Sub Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Sub Menu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
$('.menu').keydown(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
    $('ul.subMenu').toggleClass('show');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$('ul.subMenu')` to `$(this).children('ul.subMenu')`. This will search only for children of the current element (not all of them) that match the `ul.subMenu` selector (as desired).

See the jQuery [`children([selector])`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function for more info.

Comment: That was perfect and easy fix. Thank you

Comment: @DanielRubio I'm glad I helped! Make sure to accept this answer (check the green checkmark to the left off this answer) to show the community that it solved your problem!

Comment: now if I wanted to close the first menu list when I open the second one, Would I have to set this up differently, Would I use a addClass instead of toggle.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can use this Code..**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.menu').on("click",function(){
                $(this).find(".subMenu").toggle();
                $(this).siblings().find(".subMenu").hide();
              });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
           <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="menu "><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <ul class="subMenu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Sub Menu 1</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="subMenu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Sub Menu 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Sub Menu 2</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is defining a CSS class `.collapse` to collapse each `ul` with class `.subMenu` within currently focused `li`. In the script, a function is bind to the `li` using class selector, that toggles(Add or Remove) the class `.collapse`with the `ul`s.

```js
$('.menu').keyup(function(e){ 
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;   
    if(keyCode==13){
        $(this).find('ul.subMenu').toggleClass('collapse');
    }
});
```

```css
.collapse{
  height:0;  
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li class="menu" autofocus><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li>
        <a href="">Sub Menu 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li>
        <a href="">Sub Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Sub Menu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```